# Are there any merge tools to auto-merge changes made to the same line (but in different places)

Tags: git, merge

This is a bit of a special case, I know that in the general case (i.e. computer code) it is not safe to automatically merge two changes to the same line in different branches.

However, in this case the line in question is an English sentence, and the changes are productization. An example:

Merge base:

> Find tweets from your iPhone or Android phone, or write a tweet of your own!

Branch 1:

> Find %(PRODUCT:MESSAGE_PLURAL)s from your iPhone or Android phone, or write a tweet of your own!

Branch 2:

> Find tweets from your iPhone or Android phone, or write a %(PRODUCT:MESSAGE)s of your own!

This is a trivial case to merge by hand, but unfortunately we are generating a very large number of these conflicts right now. Is there a mergetool out there that can do this? (Or any other way to automate this process)

Comment: Well first check out `git rerere` so you don't find yourself solving exactly the same conflicts every time you conduct the merge.

Comment: Git rerere is awesome, but sadly the conflicts are all different.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do this in my merge tool of choice, Araxis Merge and came up empty.

There was a recent question on the Beyond Compare forum about this: http://www.scootersoftware.com/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=9411 note the developers of Beyond Compare aren't even aware of a tool that does this.

A couple options: Araxis Merge and (I believe) Beyond Compare both allow you to control merge outcomes with regex. You might explore that.

Another option, `git diff branch1..branch2 -U99999 --word-diff > file.txt`

What you'd have then would be: 
    Find [-%(PRODUCT:MESSAGE_PLURAL)s-]{+tweets+} from your iPhone or Android phone, or write a [-tweet-]{+%(PRODUCT:MESSAGE)s+} of your own!

I'm not really a developer, but if I were, I think I'd be able to write a regex that identified instances of `[-*-]` or `{+*+}`, stripped these characters and alternately saved or deleted the contents based on the presence of `$(*)`, which seems to be a common element in the productization.

This might be a pain if there are a lot of files as it entails the extra step of mapping the `> file.txt` output to the relevant files.

Possible solution: `git ls-files -u | git diff branch1..branch2 -U99999 --word-diff > ./intermediate/filename`

That code is wrong, but you should be able to write a bash script that takes all unmerged files, saves each files' diff with the entire file's worth of context to an intermediate file, with the original file name.

Other options:

You could do merge the branches as normal, but write a script to resolve the merge conflicts for you based on the logic above albeit with the added complexity of multiple lines, parsing <<<<<<, =======, >>>>>, etc.

Someone more experienced than me might also be able to make use of `git-filter-branch`